# Auto refresh Odata connection between SharePoint list and MS Excel

Tags: list, excel, odata

I have an Odata connection set up in Excel Services to SharePoint list data. 
The Odata connection pivots the list data, then charts it in Excel Services, and the chart is hosted in SharePoint
When I add SharePoint list data I want the chart to update via Excel Services. I can refresh the data if I open Excel Online, but I can't get the data to auto refresh, or refresh via SharePoint (clicking the chart).
I believe this is not working due to trusted locations/authentication, but I'm unsure how to resolve this - if that's the issue.
Also, I'm on SP2013 Online - this may also be an issue.